# Wireguard VPN not allowing connections

Tags: ubuntu, wireguard

so I have wireguard setup on my linux server and im trying to connect to it on my windows machine. Here is the config i am using to connect to it on my windows machine.

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = hidden
Address = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
DNS = 1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = hidden
PresharedKey = hidden
Endpoint = 149.102.148.225:64071
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
```

When i press activate on my win machine it says it has activated but doesn't let me do anythhing.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the interface an address with a 32 bit net mask (`/32`), that means the address isn't part of a subnet, and the OS isn't going to automatically add a route for the addresses that are accessible through that interface.

To solve this you can either assign the addresses with a narrower mask (`/24` is probably appropriate) or you can configure the routes manually.